# index groupwise archive with solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I would like to learn if anyone has successfully indexed GroupWise archive mail into Apache Solr/lucene?

Looking for assistance on setting up a fetch.

Thank you.

Comment: Poor Analysis as there are many links available on internet for this.

Answer (score 0):

By Default, SOLR comes with clustering module i.e. carrot2
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent

Try this module and it will solve your issue.

Comment: I understand clustering but what does that have to do with fetching the content from the archive mail folders though an indexing job/fetch? - and Jayesh, I did conduct several web searches as well as the solr and lucene site themselves and nothing returned with specifics on Groupwise.  If you have such links I would appreciate them.